# I am problems getting the scene for a Java FX menu item

Tags: java, javafx, fxml, menuitem

I am working on a java assignment and so I am not quite a "Jedi Master"
when it comes Java, and in fact more at the "trainer wheels stage",
and so still coming to grips with Java FX stages and scenes..
anyway here is a some prototype code that shows the problem I am having...

[ These all reside in the testingMenuAction package]

**My main class: " testingMenuAction_main.java"**

```
package testingMenuAction;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;


public class testingMenuAction_main extends Application {
    
    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/testingMenuAction/testingMenuAction.fxml"));
        
        Scene scene = new Scene(root);
        
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

**My main Java FXML file: "testingMenuAction.fxml"**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.Menu?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.MenuBar?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.MenuItem?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.VBox?>

<AnchorPane fx:id="testingMenuActionPage" prefHeight="195.0" prefWidth="494.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/11.0.1" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="testingMenuAction.testingMenuActionController">
  <children>
      <VBox prefHeight="186.0" prefWidth="493.0">
         <children>
            <MenuBar>
              <menus>
                <Menu mnemonicParsing="false" text="Data">
                  <items>
                    <MenuItem fx:id="mnu_data_import" mnemonicParsing="false" text="Import File" />
                  </items>
                </Menu>
              </menus>
            </MenuBar>
         </children>
      </VBox>
  </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

**My controller class for my Java FXML file: "testingMenuActionController.java"**

```
package testingMenuAction;

import java.io.File;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.control.MenuItem;
import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane;
import javafx.stage.FileChooser;
import javafx.stage.FileChooser.ExtensionFilter;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.stage.Window;





public class testingMenuActionController implements Initializable {
    

    
    @FXML
    private AnchorPane testingMenuActionPage;
    
    @FXML
    private MenuItem mnu_data_import;
    //this tests the operation of the alert dialog
    
   //private Stage export_chooser_stage;
    


    
 
    //===================================================================================================================
    /*
     * This method will initialiise the UI
     */
    
    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) 
    {
        
        //--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        /*
         * This  is the mnu_data_import.setOnAction((event)
         */
            mnu_data_import.setOnAction((event) -> 
            {
                System.out.println("You clicked to Import Data");
                FileChooser fileChooser = new FileChooser();
                fileChooser.setTitle("Open Resource File");
                fileChooser.getExtensionFilters().addAll(
                 new ExtensionFilter("Text Files", "*.csv")  );
                File selectedFile = fileChooser.showOpenDialog(  mnu_data_import.getScene().getWindow()  );
                String FileNamePath = selectedFile.toString();
                System.out.println("File name and path to file :" + FileNamePath);
                
                
            });// close
  
        
    }// close public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb)     

  
    
}// close public class testingMenuActionController
```

The compiler is complaining with the following instruction:

```
"File selectedFile = fileChooser.showOpenDialog(  mnu_data_import.getScene().getWindow()  );"
```

Giving the following error message...
**"The method getScene() is undefined for the type MenuItem"**

Unfortunately my experinece with Java Windows, Stage, Scenes, and Nodes is still small
[as I still on my "trainer wheels.."]...

As a result, would some  one be able to help me?

Comment: Instead of `mnu_data_import.getScene().getWindow()` try `testingMenuActionPage .getScene().getWindow()`

Comment: Thank you, that worked but I got an exception...
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.NullPointerException
at testingMenuAction.testingMenuActionController.lambda$0(testingMenuActionController.java:57)

What do you suggest as the best way to handle the Exception?

Comment: Is `String FileNamePath = selectedFile.toString();` line 57? If so, then note that `showOpenDialog` can return `null` if the user closes the dialog without choosing a file. You have to handle that case gracefully (i.e. check for `null`).

Comment: And side note: Trying to get the `Scene` from a `MenuItem` would probably not work as you expect. A `MenuItem` is not a `Node` but is mirrored by a `Node` behind-the-scenes. However, that `Node` is typically displayed in a `ContextMenu` or some other popup. This means calling `menuItem.getScene().getWindow()` would, if that were valid code, probably give you the `ContextMenu` and not the main `Stage` of the application; that could cause issues since the popup usually disappears after pressing an item.

Comment: java naming conventions .. how often do you need to be reminded (and downvoted ;) before you use them?

Comment: _my experinece with Java Windows, Stage, Scenes, and Nodes is still small_ then it's time for working through a decent basic tutorial (the javafx tag wiki has references)

Answer (score 3):

There is no such method `getScene()` for the class `MenuItem`, see [this documentation page](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/MenuItem.html).

I guess you are trying to find the owner window so you can pass it to the `showOpenDialog()` method. What you can do is indeed use the method `getScene()`, not on your `MenuItem` (since it does not have a `getScene()` method) but rather on your root element, in this case `testingMenuActionPage`. (Note: it can be called on any element inheriting the class `Node`)

```
mnu_data_import.setOnAction((event) ->
{
    System.out.println("You clicked to Import Data");
    FileChooser fileChooser = new FileChooser();
    fileChooser.setTitle("Open Resource File");
    fileChooser.getExtensionFilters().addAll(new ExtensionFilter("Text Files", "*.csv")  );
    File selectedFile = fileChooser.showOpenDialog(testingMenuActionPage.getScene().getWindow());
    String FileNamePath = selectedFile.toString();
    System.out.println("File name and path to file :" + FileNamePath);
});
```

Comment: Note that `selectedFile` can potentially be `null`.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested in my comment, instead of `mnu_data_import.getScene().getWindow()` change it to `testingMenuActionPage.getScene().getWindow()` because `MenuItem` does not have `getScene()` Method directly and also check if the `File` exists/has been choosed.

Your `initialize` Method could look like this:

```
@Override
public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) 
{
    
    //--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    /*
     * This  is the mnu_data_import.setOnAction((event)
     */
        mnu_data_import.setOnAction((event) -> 
        {
            System.out.println("You clicked to Import Data");
            FileChooser fileChooser = new FileChooser();
            fileChooser.setTitle("Open Resource File");
            fileChooser.getExtensionFilters().addAll(
             new ExtensionFilter("Text Files", "*.csv")  );
            File selectedFile = fileChooser.showOpenDialog(testingMenuActionPage .getScene().getWindow());
            // check if file has been choosed
            if (selectedFile != null) {

              String FileNamePath = selectedFile.toString();
              System.out.println("File name and path to file :" + FileNamePath);


            } else {
            // file not choosed, cancel button has been clicked
            // do something here
            }
            
        });// close

    
}// close public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb)
```

Comment: Thank you for your help with this, it has been part of a quite challenging assignment for my university course in Java. I really appreciate your help thank you

Comment: No problem, I am glad that it helped. Please mark it as answer so other users can find it useful! 

Comment: why do you repeat the earlier answer (adding only the minor detail of a null check) ? that's plagiating ..

Comment: @kleopatra - really now? Look at my first comment under the question. This comment was before user WonkOn wrote his answer...so it was my answer/comment that was copied...don’t you think?

Comment: smithnblack thank you, but dumb question how do I mark it as "answered"? Do I respond to "Answer Your Question"?

Comment: Have a look over here: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235